# Закрытие div при клике вне его

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно закрыть `div`, если клик был вне его области.

Имеем:

```js
function backcall() {
    var status = document.getElementById('backcallmsgdiv');
    status.style.height = "500px";
    status.style.border = "1px solid #A52629";
    status.style.overflow = "visible";       
}

function closebc() {
    var status = document.getElementById('backcallmsgdiv');
    status.style.height = "0px";
    status.style.border = "0px solid #A52629";
    status.style.overflow = "hidden";
    status.addEventListener("click", stopEvent, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="cl1">
    <a href="#" onclick="backcall()">Свяжитесь с нами</a>
</div>
<div id="backcallmsgdiv">
    <a href="#" onclick="closebc()" >
        <div id="close">X</div>
    </a>
    <div class="tre"></div>
</div>
```

Как закрыть блок при клике вне его? Пробовал повесить функцию на `body` (при клике на `body` закрытие блока, но он тогда просто не открывается).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Идея состоит в том, чтобы запретить продвижение события `click` по DOM вверх, если клик произведён по элементу *"Свяжитесь с нами"* или `#backcallmsgdiv` (за исключением `#close`). В таком случае можно закрывать окно по клику в `document`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDomReady);

function onDomReady() {
    var status = document.getElementById('backcallmsgdiv');
    var conactUs = document.getElementById('contactUs');
    var close = document.getElementById('close');
    
    conactUs.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        status.style.height = "500px";
        status.style.border = "1px solid #A52629";
        status.style.overflow = "visible";
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    
    status.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    
    function closebc() {
        status.style.height = "0px";
        status.style.border = "0px solid #A52629";
        status.style.overflow = "hidden";
    }
    
    document.addEventListener('click', closebc);
    close.addEventListener('click', closebc);   
};
```

```html
<div class="cl1">
    <a id="contactUs" href="#">Свяжитесь с нами</a>
</div>
<div id="backcallmsgdiv">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="close">X</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, поуду обдумывать ваш код

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов на здоровье. Логика кода ваша, только `onclick` заменены на `addEventListener` и добавлен тот самый _click на `body`_.

Answer (score 0):

> попробывал повесить функцию на body (при клике на боде закрытие блока, но он тогда просто не открывается)

Забыл проверить, что кликается не что-то внутри этого div'а.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function listenClick(selector) {
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) { // событие клика по веб-документу    
    if (!selector.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
      &&
      !selector.has(e.target).length //не по дочерним
      &&
      !selector.parent(selector).has(e.target).length) { // не по родителю      
      // здесь анимация к примеру fadeOut() 
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  });
```