# Как убрать class при клике вне области элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как закрыть меню и все подменю при клике вне его области?

`toggle` оставить как есть, но сделать чтобы внутрение еще закрывались

За открытие меню и подменю это отвечает класс `.active`

Как то с проверкой чтобы оптимизация еще была

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('.sidebar-submenu > span')) {
    e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 8px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
}
.sidebar-logotype {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 40px 0 2px;
  color: #000;
  height: inherit;
}
.sidebar-logotype img {
  width: 18px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
.sidebar-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.sidebar-menu a,
.sidebar-menu span {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sidebar-submenu span > i {
  margin: 2px 0 0 6px;
  transition: transform .1s;
}
.sidebar-submenu div span > i {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.sidebar-submenu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar-submenu > div {
  display: none;
}
.sidebar-submenu.active > div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 8px);
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  min-width: 72px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.sidebar-submenu .sidebar-submenu.active > div {
  top: -3px;
  left: calc(100% + 8px);
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.sidebar-submenu.active > div:before,
.sidebar-submenu.active > div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
.sidebar-submenu.active > div:before {
  top: -10px;
  left: 22px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}
.sidebar-submenu.active > div:after {
  top: -10px;
  left: 22px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}
.sidebar-submenu .sidebar-submenu.active > div:before {
  top: 10px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #000;
}
.sidebar-submenu .sidebar-submenu.active > div:after {
  top: 10px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #fff;
}
.sidebar-menu a:hover,
.sidebar-menu span:hover,
.sidebar-submenu.active > span {
  color: #3ca4e7;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#" class="sidebar-logotype">Logo</a>
  <div class="sidebar-menu">
    <div class="sidebar-submenu">
      <span>Menu</span>
      <div>
        <div><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
        <div class="sidebar-submenu">
          <span>Submenu</span>
          <div>
            <div><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-submenu">
      <span>Menu 2</span>
      <div>
        <div><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Закрытие div при клике вне его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433249/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-div-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как закрыть меню и все подменю при клике вне его области?

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('.sidebar-submenu > span')) {
    e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
  }
  if (!e.target.closest('.sidebar-menu')) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-menu .active').forEach(o => {
      o.classList.remove('active')
    })
  }
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 8px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
}

.sidebar-logotype {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 40px 0 2px;
  color: #000;
  height: inherit;
}

.sidebar-logotype img {
  width: 18px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.sidebar-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar-menu a,
.sidebar-menu span {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar-submenu span>i {
  margin: 2px 0 0 6px;
  transition: transform .1s;
}

.sidebar-submenu div span>i {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.sidebar-submenu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar-submenu>div {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar-submenu.active>div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 8px);
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  min-width: 72px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.sidebar-submenu .sidebar-submenu.active>div {
  top: -3px;
  left: calc(100% + 8px);
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.sidebar-submenu.active>div:before,
.sidebar-submenu.active>div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.sidebar-submenu.active>div:before {
  top: -10px;
  left: 22px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}

.sidebar-submenu.active>div:after {
  top: -10px;
  left: 22px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}

.sidebar-submenu .sidebar-submenu.active>div:before {
  top: 10px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #000;
}

.sidebar-submenu .sidebar-submenu.active>div:after {
  top: 10px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #fff;
}

.sidebar-menu a:hover,
.sidebar-menu span:hover,
.sidebar-submenu.active>span {
  color: #3ca4e7;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#" class="sidebar-logotype">Logo</a>
  <div class="sidebar-menu">
    <div class="sidebar-submenu">
      <span>Menu</span>
      <div>
        <div><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
        <div class="sidebar-submenu">
          <span>Submenu</span>
          <div>
            <div><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А подскажешь как сделать если открыто одно меню при клике на другое предыдущее закрывалось? Обновил вопрос, добавил там второе меню

Comment: Сделал, добавил в условие такую штуку `[...document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-submenu')].map(el => { if (e.target.parentNode != el) el.classList.remove('active') });`

Comment: @avory, `map` возвращает новый массив. Если он никому далее не нужен - вернее использовать `forEach`, так и в массив коллекцию не нужно будет переделывать.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, вы можете вместе с меню отрисовывать прозрачную подложку на весь экран и отслеживать клик по ней, по которому будете убирать класс активности с меню